# Process not receiving SIGTERM in Docker container

Tags: docker, signals, container

I've got a simple Python process running in a Docker container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install python3
COPY app.py /app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./app.py"]
```

app.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pass
```

It runs just fine.  However, I've noticed that the process is unaffected by `SIGTERM`.  I.e.,

```bash
# In container
kill -s TERM `pgrep python3`
```

doesn't do anything.  However,

```bash
kill -s INT `pgrep python3`
```

raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` in the process as expected.

I ran

```bash
grep Sig /proc/`pgrep python3`/status
```

in the container and got

```
SigQ:   1/127222
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001001000
SigCgt: 0000000180000002
```

`SIGTERM` is 15 so why isn't it going through?  If I run the Python script in my host (also Ubuntu), `SIGTERM` kills it as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Docker containers have no `init` process, the Python process is running at PID 1.  According to [`man 2 kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html),

> The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1, the init
> process, are those for which init has explicitly installed signal
> handlers.  This is done to assure the system is not brought down
> accidentally.

The reason why `SIGINT` works is because Python registers a handler for that signal.  So, you can do something similar:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Exiting')
    exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
    while True:
        pass
```

Alternatively, you can tell Docker to run the container with an `init` process:

```bash
docker run -it --init my_image
```