# Process not stopping even after receiving Ctrl-Z

Tags: ssh, process, tty, signals

I was learning about signal handlers. I wrote a simple python script to handle and print all signal it gets. Then I ran that script on a remote machine through `ssh`. Then when I send Ctrl C signal, the remote process gets interrupted as expected. On contrast, when I send Ctrl Z signal, the remote process does not get stopped as I was expecting.

First I thought Ctrl Z might not be reaching the remote script. But when I hooked custom handlers, it was detecting Ctrl Z being sent.

Then I thought may be Ctrl Z is being ignored by the process. But when I print the current handler for SIGTSTP, I was hoping for SIG_IGN. But it was SIG_DFL (which for SIGTSTP means to stop the process afaik).

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Command to run ssh:

```
ssh ubuntu16x64-1 -t 'python3 ~/sig_check.py'
```

Sig-check python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import signal, errno
import time, os, sys

all_sigs = list(signal.Signals)

open('sig_log.txt', 'w').close()

def print_sig(num, frame):
    with open('sig_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(num))
    print(num)

for sig in all_sigs:
    if sig == 20: # SIGTSTP
        print(sig, signal.getsignal(sig))
        continue # commenting this would set handler for Ctrl Z
    try:
        signal.signal(sig, print_sig)
    except OSError:
        print('OSerr: Skipping %s' % (sig))
    except ValueError:
        print('Valerr: Skipping %s' % (sig))

print("Process pid %d" % (os.getpid()))
print("Parent pid %d" % (os.getppid()))

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    pass
```

**EDIT:** Burried in the last paragraph of [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html) page, I found one scenario where this can happen. That is, when the process receiving SIGTSTP is in an Orphaned Process Group. But I'm not sure if this case comes under that category.

Comment: Likely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735792/367454